# Java, android LibGDX - gradient filled circle

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Is there a way to fill cricle with a gradient? I've found this option for the rectangle, but no for the circle.

Something like

`shapeRenderer.filledRect(x, y, width, height, lightBlue, lightBlue, darkBlue, darkBlue);`

but for the circle.

It would be even better to fill with the gradient only circle's border (to be precise, I need circle with a hole inside - something like a donut. But if there's no option like this, I can draw another circle onto this one).

Image is not an option, It would be a lot of different colors, possibly even changing in time.

Comment: I'd like to know more about the result you want to get, like: Do you want the gradient to start at the center and change to another color the closer to the perimeter? Maybe you want the gradient to start at the top and change as it gets closer to the bottom

Comment: @LuisFernandoFrontanilla I'd prefer from one edge to the other - from top to the bottom, but any gradient will be better than none ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking a lot into masking since I thought that was the way to go about your question, and good news! I finally have a solution for you, hope it will be useful for you and others. I took a look here [Masking Test by mattdesl](https://gist.github.com/mattdesl/6076849) all credits to him

```
private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

@Override
public void create() {
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    //1. clear screen
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //2. clear our depth buffer with 1.0
    Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //3. set the function to LESS
    Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LESS);

    //4. enable depth writing
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //5. Enable depth writing, disable RGBA color writing
    Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);

    ///////////// Draw mask shape(s)

    //6. render your primitive shapes
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

    shapeRenderer.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f);
    shapeRenderer.circle(50, 50, 50);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(0f, 1f, 0f, 0.5f);

    shapeRenderer.end();

    ///////////// Draw sprite(s) to be masked

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_EQUAL);
    shapeRenderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 100, 100, Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE);
    shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

Keep in mind this also works for `Sprites`, `Textures` and `TextureRegions` rendered by a `SpriteBatch`!